# Creating a column of unique visits per sampling site

Tags: r

I want to create an extra column in my data (dat$visit_no) that numbers visits to each site from 1 to the maximum number of visits (e.g. for site A1 this would be 2). The number of unique visits per site can be seen in the sample column. However, what I am not sure about is how to do this if sites were visited on different dates and when each site was visited a different number of times. Any help would be appreciated, sample data is given below.

Example data:

```
> dat 
   site       date N_days         sample        family secondOrder acd
1    A1 21/05/2012      3 A_1_21/05/2012      Aderidae          A4   2
2    A1 22/05/2012      5 A_1_22_05_2012     Carabidae          A4   2
3    A1 21/05/2012      3 A_1_21/05/2012     Leiodidae          A4   2
4    A1 22/05/2012      5 A_1_22_05_2012      Aderidae          A4   2
5    A2 05/06/2012      3 A_2_05/06/2012     Carabidae          A4   5
6    A2 07/06/2012      3 A_2_07/06/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   5
7    A2 08/06/2012      3 A_2_08/06/2012     Leiodidae          A4   5
8    A2 05/06/2012      3 A_2_05/06/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   5
9    A2 07/06/2012      3 A_2_07/06/2012     Leiodidae          A4   5
10   A2 08/06/2012      3 A_2_08/06/2012 Curculionidae          A4   5
11   A3 12/03/2012      5 A_3_12/03/2012 Curculionidae          A4   4
12   A3 17/04/2012      3 A_3_17/04/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   4
13   A3 18/05/2012      5 A_3_18/05/2012      Aderidae          A4   4
14   A3 12/03/2012      5 A_3_12/03/2012 Curculionidae          A4   4
15   A3 17/04/2012      3 A_3_17/04/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   4
16   A3 18/05/2012      5 A_3_18/05/2012      Aderidae          A4   4
```

Comment: How do you uniquely identify a visit?

Comment: How would your expected output based on your shown data look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you want this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date),
         visit_no = dense_rank(date))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 8
#> # Groups:   site [3]
#>    site  date       N_days sample        family       secondOrder   acd visit_no
#>    <chr> <date>      <int> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>       <int>    <int>
#>  1 A1    2012-05-21      3 A_1_21/05/20~ Aderidae     A4              2        1
#>  2 A1    2012-05-22      5 A_1_22_05_20~ Carabidae    A4              2        2
#>  3 A1    2012-05-21      3 A_1_21/05/20~ Leiodidae    A4              2        1
#>  4 A1    2012-05-22      5 A_1_22_05_20~ Aderidae     A4              2        2
#>  5 A2    2012-06-05      3 A_2_05/06/20~ Carabidae    A4              5        1
#>  6 A2    2012-06-07      3 A_2_07/06/20~ Staphylinid~ A4              5        2
#>  7 A2    2012-06-08      3 A_2_08/06/20~ Leiodidae    A4              5        3
#>  8 A2    2012-06-05      3 A_2_05/06/20~ Staphylinid~ A4              5        1
#>  9 A2    2012-06-07      3 A_2_07/06/20~ Leiodidae    A4              5        2
#> 10 A2    2012-06-08      3 A_2_08/06/20~ Curculionid~ A4              5        3
#> 11 A3    2012-03-12      5 A_3_12/03/20~ Curculionid~ A4              4        1
#> 12 A3    2012-04-17      3 A_3_17/04/20~ Staphylinid~ A4              4        2
#> 13 A3    2012-05-18      5 A_3_18/05/20~ Aderidae     A4              4        3
#> 14 A3    2012-03-12      5 A_3_12/03/20~ Curculionid~ A4              4        1
#> 15 A3    2012-04-17      3 A_3_17/04/20~ Staphylinid~ A4              4        2
#> 16 A3    2012-05-18      5 A_3_18/05/20~ Aderidae     A4              4        3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` with `match`

```
transform(dat,  visit_no = ave(date, site, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))
   site       date N_days         sample        family secondOrder acd visit_no
1    A1 21/05/2012      3 A_1_21/05/2012      Aderidae          A4   2        1
2    A1 22/05/2012      5 A_1_22_05_2012     Carabidae          A4   2        2
3    A1 21/05/2012      3 A_1_21/05/2012     Leiodidae          A4   2        1
4    A1 22/05/2012      5 A_1_22_05_2012      Aderidae          A4   2        2
5    A2 05/06/2012      3 A_2_05/06/2012     Carabidae          A4   5        1
6    A2 07/06/2012      3 A_2_07/06/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   5        2
7    A2 08/06/2012      3 A_2_08/06/2012     Leiodidae          A4   5        3
8    A2 05/06/2012      3 A_2_05/06/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   5        1
9    A2 07/06/2012      3 A_2_07/06/2012     Leiodidae          A4   5        2
10   A2 08/06/2012      3 A_2_08/06/2012 Curculionidae          A4   5        3
11   A3 12/03/2012      5 A_3_12/03/2012 Curculionidae          A4   4        1
12   A3 17/04/2012      3 A_3_17/04/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   4        2
13   A3 18/05/2012      5 A_3_18/05/2012      Aderidae          A4   4        3
14   A3 12/03/2012      5 A_3_12/03/2012 Curculionidae          A4   4        1
15   A3 17/04/2012      3 A_3_17/04/2012 Staphylinidae          A4   4        2
16   A3 18/05/2012      5 A_3_18/05/2012      Aderidae          A4   4        3
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(site = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
"A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), date = c("21/05/2012", 
"22/05/2012", "21/05/2012", "22/05/2012", "05/06/2012", "07/06/2012", 
"08/06/2012", "05/06/2012", "07/06/2012", "08/06/2012", "12/03/2012", 
"17/04/2012", "18/05/2012", "12/03/2012", "17/04/2012", "18/05/2012"
), N_days = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 5L), sample = c("A_1_21/05/2012", "A_1_22_05_2012", 
"A_1_21/05/2012", "A_1_22_05_2012", "A_2_05/06/2012", "A_2_07/06/2012", 
"A_2_08/06/2012", "A_2_05/06/2012", "A_2_07/06/2012", "A_2_08/06/2012", 
"A_3_12/03/2012", "A_3_17/04/2012", "A_3_18/05/2012", "A_3_12/03/2012", 
"A_3_17/04/2012", "A_3_18/05/2012"), family = c("Aderidae", "Carabidae", 
"Leiodidae", "Aderidae", "Carabidae", "Staphylinidae", "Leiodidae", 
"Staphylinidae", "Leiodidae", "Curculionidae", "Curculionidae", 
"Staphylinidae", "Aderidae", "Curculionidae", "Staphylinidae", 
"Aderidae"), secondOrder = c("A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", 
"A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4"), 
    acd = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16"))
```